# MYSQL - Optimize a search table for speed (and only speed)

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

Optimize for speed.

For a catalog, I have about 150K of items:
Each item record has 8 search fields and one Json data string.
(No: int; Search fields are max 30 characters, JSON min 200 : max 2000 characters)

Item No is a unique field and is PK all others fields are not unique.

```
No  Search1 Search2 ... Search8  JSON_datastring
1     a1      a2    ...   a8      {...json...}
2     b1      b2    ...   b8      {...json...}
..
x     a1      b2    ...   c8      {...json...}
```

A user can search on each of the eight fields.
He can search on the whole field,

```
WHERE Search1 = 'x'
```

the start of the field

```
WHERE Search1 LIKE 'x%'
```

or any part of the field

```
WHERE Search1 LIKE '%x%'
```

---

My first approach is to keep all the data in on table and put an index on each of the search colomns;
but I'm wondering if there are faster methods.

The goal here is to get all matching JSON_datastrings as fast as possible. 
'Select' speed is the only concern here (users will not make any update/insert/delete commands). 
Memory or disk space are hardly relevant for this project. 
The catalog needs updating only once a week, so import and update time is also not a big cocern.

I'm working with a MYSQL database. The data in the table is imported from a csv file each week. 
I have full control over the MYSQL database.

I expect about 60% of the searches to be on the whole field.
Current n° of records 150K with about 20K growth per year.
Concurrent users: we don't have an estimate at the moment.

Are there any suggestions on how to improve the search speed? 
I'm still in the design phase of the project.

Answer (score 1):

`LIKE %x%` will always require a full table scan. No matter the index used, you can't optimize this. Instead, you should set a `FULLTEXT` search for the field - requiring `FULLTEXT` index and modifying the query to use `MATCH ... AGAINST` instead of `LIKE`. Without knowing the exact data is hard to offer further improvements, but generally you may want to offload MySQL from the search, moving the search to a separate service (`Lucene/Solr` or `Sphinx`). They may be more suitable not only in terms of performance, but in terms of functionality, as they are built for searching.